# Remove left over gutter icon from file in Sublime Text 3

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

I'm running Sublime Text 3 (build 3083).

After adding the [Python Breakpoints](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Python%20Breakpoints) package I found that if you set a breakpoint (using the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>) and you then remove the created line (where the BP is) by *deleting it* instead of toggling it (using the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> again), an icon is left in the gutter. See:

[image]

I've tried setting the package option `gutter_icon": ""` (ie: no icon), disabling the package, and even removing the package altogether. After restarting Sublime, the left over icons are still there.

I've [asked](https://github.com/obormot/PythonBreakpoints/issues/9) the creator of the package who told me this is an issue with ST, not with the package itself.

How can I remove these icons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the information that there should be icons in the gutter persists somewhere in Sublime, even after closing it.

The solution was (found with help from plugin's creator) to close *each file* where this issue was occurring, and then re-opening them.

*Not* restarting Sublime, but closing-reopening the *file itself*.